# Kendo Grid set the minimum column width when screen is resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to set the **minimum column width** of kendo grid when **screen** is resizing?
For example I had this [grid](https://dojo.telerik.com/ODuLAyIw) and I want to set the `Description` column min width to `300px`

I have tried:

1. `media: "(min-width: 300px)"`
2. I found this [article](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/apply-minimum-width-during-column-resize) but it only works if resizing the column in the grid.

[DEMO IN DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/ODuLAyIw)

Comment: Do You want an starting width to be wider or?

Comment: @dev_in_progress doesn't matter as long the minimum column width is set. So when resize the screen the minimum width will trigger,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly putting css to element you can add class to parent element of Grid and catch the grid column class using that parent element class and then add the media query on that.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a row template, this will allow you to target individual columns with CSS and further customise sizing with using Media Queries.

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/rowtemplate

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to give a minimum width to a specific column and otherwise have it expand to take up the available space.